# .NET 4.0 Calendar control member SelectedDate is of type "DateTime?"?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-4.0

In .NET 4.0 if you create a Calendar and you look at the SelectedDate field it is of type "DateTime?".  What's the deal with the ? at the end of the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

? at the end means it's nullable, as in, the control may not have a SelectedDate at all.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 2):

? at the end means that a value type can also be null.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime?` means `Nullable<DateTime>` that's meaning that this property can hold `null`. Meanwhile just `DateTime` - cannot.

See more about [Nullable Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)